# java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: MapReduce

Tags: java, arrays, hadoop, mapreduce

Beginner level - can't get my head around this.

I wrote a MapReduce program that will result in a list of words and which line number they appear in, e.g.

- and: 4
- if: 1, 2, 3

etc. (see Sample Text below).

My code works perfectly well when there is no blank line as in line 2. But it throws an Exception 1 error for the below sample text.

From what I understand, this error indicates that there is an element in the array I am trying to access that doesn't exist - in this case there is just no element in the array for line 2. But how can I edit my code to ignore the blank line?

Here's the Mapper Code (with sample text):

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;

// SampleText:
1: if you prick us do we not bleed
2: 
3: if you tickle us do we not laugh
4: if you poison us do we not_ die and
5: ***if you wrong us shall we not revenge

public class IIndexMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text> {

    private final static Text listing = new Text();
    private Text wordText = new Text();

    @Override
    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)
                throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        //Single out line number by splitting each line by colon - first part being lineID
        String[] line = value.toString().split(": ");
        String lineID = line[0];
        listing.set(lineID);

        //Further split second part of the line by spaces
        String textStr = line[1];

        //Create an array of words contained in each line
        String [] tokens = textStr.split(" ");
        int count = tokens.length;

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            wordText.set(tokens[i]);
            context.write(wordText, listing);
        }
    }
}
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Because for line 2, there is no `line[1]` element.

Comment: Step through with a debugger and you should find the problem straight away.

Comment: Thanks @EliSadoff, I get that. Just how can I get around this?

Comment: Code dynamically to account for OutOfBounds exceptions instead of hard coding index references (especially those greater than 0) into your code. Try an `if` statement .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd rewrite the above code something like this because we are accessing Elements in String Array with checking the existence.

```
String[] line = value.toString().split(": ");
if(line.length >= 2){

    listing.set(line[0]);

    //Create an array of words contained in each line
    String [] tokens = line[1].split(" ");
    int count = tokens.length;

    for (String token : tokens){
        wordText.set(token);
        context.write(wordText, listing);
    }
} else {
    // increase the counter for tacking bad lines
    context.getCounter("INVALID_LINES").increment(1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to start by understanding how `String.split` works.  It splits the string into multiple parts around matches of the given regular expression.  In your example, it is attempting to split on ": ".  For the second line, nothing exists after ": " so the line element would be only one element long and only have a String in line[0].  When you try and access line[1], you are fetting the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException because it does not exist.

Take this simple example:

```
String sampleString = "2: ";

String[] line = sampleString.split(": ");

//Length is 1
System.out.println(line.length);

// Value is 2
System.out.println("0: " + line[0]);
// ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
System.out.println("1: " + line[1]);
```

You could protect against this problem by doing something like this:

```
if (line.length > 0) {
    //Further split second part of the line by spaces
    String textStr = line[1];

    //Create an array of words contained in each line
    String[] tokens = textStr.split(" ");
    int count = tokens.length;

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        wordText.set(tokens[i]);
        context.write(wordText, listing);
    }
}
```